# Error with multiple self-invoking functions in one script: a case for a semicolon

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, anonymous-function, self-invoking-function

In certain circumstances, having more than one self-invoking function in a single JavaScript file provokes an error. Getting the second function to return a value averts the error.

I have a barebones HTML file...

```
<script src="two.js"></script>
<script src="one.js"></script>
```

... using these scripts:

```
// two.js
(function () {
  console.log('1/2')
})()

(function () {
  console.log('2/2')
})()
```

```
// one.js
(function () {
  console.log('1/1')
})()
```

When I open the file in Chrome, I get this output:

```
1/2 two.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function two.js:6
1/1
```

Other browsers complain in their own way. In other words, having two self-invoking functions in the same script causes a problem. Having one self-invoking function per script works fine. If I comment out the second function script two.js, there is no problem.

However, if I get the second function to return a value, then there is no problem either. Everything works fine if I change two.js to this:

```
(function () {
  console.log('1/2')
})()

foo = (function () {
  console.log('2/2')
  return 'bar'
})()
```

Why does the first version fail and the second succeed?

Comment: You forgot the semicolons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the semicolons:

```
(function () {
  console.log('1/2')
})();

(function () {
  console.log('2/2')
})();
```

Otherwise  the returned value of the previous expression (`undefined`) tries to execute the next expression. Obviously `undefined` is not a function.

In the semicolonless JavaScript world, you'll often see the semicolon preceding any raw expression, such as `()`:

```
;(function(){}())
;['1','2','3'].map(Number)
```

JavaScript [will attempt to fill in the semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) you "forgot" but those expressions are ambiguous so you need to add it.

Comment: But when I execute them together in a file, I don't see this error. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing semicolons at the end of your function expressions, so the proceeding parenthetical expression is parsed as a call to the function. Since the function doesn't return a value (return value is implicitly `undefined`), the code is functionally equivalent to `undefined()` - hence the error.

Moral of the story - Don't forget your semicolons!

Comment: Well now... This is the very first time that I have encountered a real need for semicolons. You are absolutely right: adding a single semicolon in the right place solves the issue.

Comment: @JamesNewton There are other situations in which semicolons are required for the code to work correctly. As a good rule of thumb it is always best to use semicolons just in case.